# Understanding kronecker delta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How is the square matrix $\langle a''|A|a'\rangle=\langle a'|A|a'\rangle\delta_{a'a''}$

Could it be that we apply the closure property to it like

$\langle a''|A|a'\rangle=\sum_{a'}\langle a''|A|a'\rangle|a'\rangle\langle a'|=\sum_{a'}\langle a''|a'\rangle A\langle a'|a'\rangle=\langle a'|A|a'\rangle\delta_{a'a''}$

Is it even a correct method. Please help.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/690095/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic How is it related? please explain.

Comment: @Qmechanic is my method of inserting closure relation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with your summation indicies and bra/ket ordering. You can't sum over the index that you've already got in your expression for one
\begin{align*}
\langle \alpha | A |\beta\rangle = \langle \alpha | 1 A |\beta\rangle &= \sum_\gamma \langle \alpha | |\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma | A |\beta\rangle \\
&= \sum_\gamma \delta_{\alpha, \gamma} \langle \gamma | A | \beta\rangle \\
&= \langle \alpha | A |\beta\rangle
\end{align*}
Inserting the completeness relation here doesn't help you, it's more of a definition for a diagonal matrix. Only matrix elements on the diagonal i.e. $A_{ii}$ are non zero. All the other entries $A_{i\neq j}$ are zero.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the closure property, rather, the properties of kronecker delta function itself.

The kronecker delta function $\delta(x_0,x_1) = 1$ 'if and only if' $x_0 = x_1$.

What the statement $$\langle a''|A|a'\rangle = \langle a''|A|a''\rangle \delta_{a''a'} = \langle a'|A|a\rangle \delta_{a"a'}$$ implies is that the square matrix is diagonal. The off-diadgonal elements are zero i.e. $a' \neq a'' \implies \delta_{a''a'} =0$ and hence, the matrix element is also zero.